# Rewrite rule challenge in nginx

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I have this old URL from our previous site

http://site.com/fixed-word/changing-category/12345-title-of-story

where the "variables" are

changing-category: example sports, politics etc.

and

12345-title-of-story: 12345 is the old id and the rest is the story slug / title

The new site uses only the story slug in this format

http://site.com/another-fixed-word/title-of-story

Is it possible to create a 301 rewrite rule in nginx to achieve this ?

I tried this:

rewrite ^/fixed-word/([^\?]+)$/([^\?]+)$ /index.php?tipo=old_article&slug=$1 last;

And the idea was to get the slug in php and remove the numeric id from the slug (12345-) but does not work, aging returns 404

Any advice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression is completely wrong:
`^/fixed-word/([^\?]+)$/([^\?]+)$`

If you just need to create a 301 redirect, then you should use this:

```
location /fixed-word/ {
    rewrite ^/fixed-word/(?:[^/]+)/(?:\d+)-(.+)$ /another-fixed-word/$1 permanent;
}
```

- man pcrepattern
- man pcresyntax
- http://nginx.org/r/rewrite
- http://nginx.org/r/location